# How to set focus on a TEdit in TscGPToolPager OnChangePage event?

Tags: delphi

I use `TscGPToolPager`, which inherits from `TWinControl`.

Unfortunately, there is no `OnShow` event on `TscGPToolPagerPage` (also inherits from `TWinControl`).

I try to set focus on a `TEdit`, which is located on chosen page, in the `OnChange` event, but it doesn't work as I expect.

Anyone maybe know this case? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not asking for support from [the vendor](https://www.almdev.com/prods/stylecontrols/stylecontrols_scs.html)?

Comment: @AmigoJack I am afraid it's a general problem with setting focus in this event.